# How to set Ext.Form dirty state?

Tags: extjs

How to change the state `dirty` of a form to `false`?

Is there something like `setDirty(false)` method of `Ext.Form.Panel`?

**UPD:**

My task is to track `Form` dirty state for enabling docked SAVE button to become enabled only if there are any changes in the form.

I'm tracking `dirtychange` event with:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'form': {
            dirtychange: function(form) {
                alert('change');      
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But when I'm loading a record through `loadRecord()` method into the Form I'm geting `chage` alert while loading record and Form becomes dirty after Record was loaded.

I'd like to reset `dirty` state of a Form right after Record loading and start tracking `dirtychange` event on record filled form.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **Correction**
>
> There is a property available which changes the original-value when a value get set.
>
> *trackResetOnLoad: true*
>
> See this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/SgkzZ/)**

*Old answer below might be quit inconvenient but I let it unchanged*

**First I have to say you will not find any such method**

And that's because the form has not such a state, the fields have it. All what the form does is iterating over each field and check if it is dirty. If any field is dirty it will be checked if this value (the dirty mark) has changed since the last check and if so the `dirtychange` event is fired. Then this get saved as last check (`wasDirty`)

**Now let's look at the fields cause they really trigger it:**

They are checking `onChange` and `onReset` if the field is dirty by checking `!me.isEqual(me.getValue(), me.originalValue)` where `originalValue` is the value that was set the time `initValue` was called.

**Now what's to do to 'set' the Form no longer 'dirty'**

Iterate over all fields of the form by using `getFields()` on `Ext.form.Basic` now we will set the current value as original value (reset will now reset to this value) by calling `initValue` on each field and that's it.

*wrong code removed*

**Edit**

Well I've modified my last code from above to

```
var items = form.getForm().getFields().items,
      i = 0,
      len = items.length;
  for(; i < len; i++) {
    var c = items[i];
    if(c.mixins && c.mixins.field && typeof c.mixins.field['initValue'] == 'function') {
      c.mixins.field.initValue.apply(c);
      c.wasDirty = false;
    }
}
```

and forked a **[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sZR8M/)**. The Button will stay inactive till any changes are detected and will again set inactive if you remove the changes. Play around with it I guess this is what you'Re looking for.

Comment: Looks like `Ext.Form.Field` doesn't have `setDirty()` method too.

Comment: @s.webbandit I found a property which does nearly the same (see my edit)

Answer (score 1):

There is the method [`reset()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-reset). If used without an argument it retains the form data loaded with `loadRecord()`.

So if you call `reset()` after loading the data, your form should not be dirty any more.

```
myForm.loadRecord(record);
myForm.reset();
```

I think, the `dirtychange` event will also be called by loading the data, but after the `reset()` you can check the form with `isDirty()`.

Comment: This is not correct, it will only retain the record instance that was bound to the form but not the loaded values.

Comment: Did you read the ExtJS documentation for `Ext.form.Basic.reset()`? I had the problem, that I wanted to check if a dialog has changes by the user when the user clicked on "close". If yes I warn the user, that there are unsaved changes. I am loading some data with `loadRecord()` into the form. I always had my form dirty since I found that a `reset()` creates a not dirty state after loading the data.

Comment: Did you read it? But it is important at which time the record is loaded cause if a form get rendered and shown empty this values is stored as `originalValue` and `reset()` will restore the this `originalValue` to the field. The boolean arg will just wipe the record reference if set to true. So if you load a record after the field was initialized reset will wipe all values from the fields unless you either load the record before the field is initalized or set the trackResetOnLoad property to true (which will override the originalValue)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround here is to use a hidden field and set it's value to force the form dirty. We use this in widgets which do not contain form fields. To set the form dirty, we simply change the value of the hidden-field, to set it clean, we reset it to the original value.